# C# - Create new URI object to point to a Local file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, uri

How can I create a URL object that points to a file that is Local to my web application I thought this would work:

```
var myURI = new Uri("~/Content/css/pdfX.css");
```

but I am getting this error:

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use Server.MapPath to point to a local file or folder. Try this please : var myURI = New Uri(Server.MapPath("~/Content/css/pdfX.css"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the virtual path that you have to the corresponding physical file path. You do that with the `Server.MapPath` method.

```
var myURI = new Uri(Server.MapPath("~/Content/css/pdfX.css"));
```